# How to increment a value in redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis, ioredis

I am trying to increment a value for a key-value in redis, if the value already exists in redis. For instance if we have

```
client.get(key, function checkRedis(err, data){
  var redisData = JSON.parse(data);
  if(redisData === null){
     //do something
  }else{
     client.incr(redisData.val);
  }
});
```

From my understanding, according to the documentation using "incr" should automatically increment that specific value by 1. But i am unable to see this happen successfuly, am i missing something

Answer (score 3):

You need to give `client` the `key` not the value.

I believe the below will do what you need.

```
client.get(key, function checkRedis(err, data){
  var redisData = JSON.parse(data);
  if(redisData === null){
     //do something
  }else{
     redisData.val++;
     client.set(key, redisData);
  }
});
```

Comment: what if the structure looks like the following
parentKey:{
   key1:{
     val: 0 
  },
 .......
}

and i have to increment val

Comment: @RajPowar than you'll have to do `client.incr("key1")`

Comment: i don't know anything about `ioredis` but `redis` is a key value store.  To my knowledge you can't increment the value of the property of an object.  I've updated my answer - it might help

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use the INCR key to increment value in redis**

```
   const redisClient = require('ioredis');
   const name = 'Bob';
   redisClient.incr('id', (err, id) =>
   {
      redisClient.hmset('user:' + id, 'username', name);
   });
```